# Facebook "Like" Button opens popup window, and nothing happens?

Tags: facebook, api, plugins, button, facebook-like

I've been trying to use the Like button generated here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

But so far, the only thing that happens when I click on it is:

1. Popup opens, facebook link loads on the popup but nothing happens (blank page)
2. The button on the page changes to "1 Like" and then changes back again to "0"

No noted errors in Firebug.

I've been searching and searching for an answer to this, but so far have come up with nothing.  Not sure if anyone has a solution to this?

I've already checked the cookies thing with Firefox, but even with Chrome and Safari this is a problem.

No answers here either:
https://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=14696440021&topic=16716

It's odd because I've seen some sites where the Facebook Like button works - is there something I'm missing?  I'm copying + pasting it exactly as it's generated.

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=APPIDHERE&amp;href&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=60&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:60px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

OR

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APPIDHERE&amp;xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="" send="false" layout="box_count" width="60" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same problem with my one of Wordpress post.

can u tel me where u r using it? with what  kind of content.

Edit:

`<fb:like href="http://yourdomain.com/page.html" send="false" layout="box_count" width="60" show_faces="false" action="like" font=""></fb:like>`

Comment: I'm using it on a regular php-generated page (so plain HTML, since it's client-side).

Comment: i checked ur comment on @alex post, there is issue with your URL that is to be liked. is there a way you can post your FB code or share that link of page where you are facing problem?

Comment: I checked ur FB like button code, u missed the href. add that page title to get that working. check my answer, i m editing it.

Comment: check my answer now, and replace href link with your link.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - I tried that, but then checked the notes on the FB developer page (it says if you leave the href blank, it defaults to the current page it's on, which is what I want it to do).

Comment: @Jay can u share the link of page on which you are facing problems?

Comment: It's weird, but after restarting my computer the whole thing worked (original code and everything).  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue that's particular to your url, and should not be related to enabling third party cookies. Have you tried putting your url (the one to be liked) through the linter on the developer site to see if there are any errors?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I ran it, and got some "missing" errors: 
Required Property Missing og:title is required
Required Property Missing og:type is required
Required Property Missing og:url is required
Required Property Missing og:image is required

Comment: I'm not sure how this should be edited?  Since the code was generated by FB's API?